# Div height:0px does not work?

Tags: css, html

```
<div style="height:0px;max-height:0px">
</div>
```

Setting a div height to 0px does not seem to work.

The div expands to show its contents, how do we prevent this from happening?

Comment: Note: If you use bootstrap etc. it often sets `min-height: 1px;` somewhere deep, make sure to set it to 0.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you *really* want to be sure it's gonna be have no height you could use something like this:

```
display: block;
line-height:0;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
```

If you're still having problems on IE, you could also add

```
zoom: 1;
```

to it in a stylesheet targeted at IE with a conditional comment. That'll trigger the hasLayout property in IE.

And display:none isn't the same as setting it to zero height. Just look at the various clearfix solutions for a case where *not* removing it from the flow is crucial.

Comment: you'd also want to ensure padding: 0;

honestly easiest way to handle issues like this is to always start with a reset.css - makes debugging these things for x-browser compliance much easier

Comment: you might want to add position: relative; too. it seems like that's also required in some cases.

Answer (score 32):

Set `overflow:hidden`. Otherwise the content will expand the wrapping element.

Comment: No, the content will overflow the wrapping element and be visible outside it. The container won't expand (except in some Microsoft browsers (but not in some rendering modes)).

Answer (score 9):

Try to also set `line-height: 0;`

And if you want to hide your `div` completely, use `display: none;`

Comment: It sounds like what the OP really wants is "display: none;".

Comment: I have the same requirement, the 'display:none' made it work for me

Answer (score 7):

For me, on Windows 10, Firefox 58.0.1, it wouldn't hide completely unless using this:

```
display: block !important;
line-height: 0 !important;
height: 0 !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
zoom: 1 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
margin-bottom: 0;
border: none;
```

Comment: `padding: 0` did the trick for me

Comment: please read notes about `zoom` on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) before using, else works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try overflow:hidden

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding "overflow:hidden" to the style

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said which browser you're using, but I'm assuming IE, as it's the only browser I know of which mistakes `height`  for `min-height` . Like everyone else has already said, `overflow:hidden;` will work, or `line-height: 0;`, but you only need one of them.

Setting `height: 0;` will have allready triggered IEs hasLayout, so no need for `zoom:1;` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do, out of context, but try this:

```
display:none;
overflow:hidden:
height:0;
line-height:0;
border:0;
margin:0;
```

Comment: with `display:none` none of the other properties need be stated

Answer (score 0):

```
#yiv1734505183 .yiv1734505183portrait{
    display:none;
    font-size:0;
    max-height:0;
    line-height:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

@media (min-width:481px){
    #yiv1734505183 .yiv1734505183mobile-hide{
        display:block;
        overflow:visible;
        width:auto !important;
        max-height:inherit !important;
        min-height:auto !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width:481px){
    #yiv1734505183 .yiv1734505183portrait{
        display:none;
        font-size:0;
        line-height:0;
        min-height:0;
        overflow
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
.zippy{
    padding: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cover this well. Just want to add that if you have tried everything else and the `<div>` still is visible, then there may be a `min-height:` that is the culprit.