# div Height: 0 problem in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

to `clear: both` my content i use this:

CSS:

```
.clr {
  clear: both;
  height: 0; /* i have tried 0.001em to */
  line-height: .001em;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="clr">&nbsp;</div>
```

it works perfectly in every navigator. But in IE 7 & 8 the div still have a height of a few pixels. How can i avoid this?

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950829/div-height0px-does-not-work

Comment: no its not. My overflow is already hidden, and my lineheight is set to

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a IE font problem.

Add

```
font-size: 0;
```

to your css declaration

Answer (score 4):

Just coming across this and the answer Ben gave makes sense but it was incomplete in dec of 2011 on IE 7 (legacy support necessitates this.

`font-size:0;` is a good start but didn't initially do it for me.

Along this line of thought, you need to be mindful of line-height. If you set line-height higher up in the DOM, likely due to the nature of these things, it get inherited ( as was happening to me )

If you have set line-height on a parent, be sure to set it explicitly on the child you are trying to use to force the clear:

```
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
```

-Brandt

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "easy clearing" (or "clearfix") for markup-less clearing. It's usually much simpler:

http://oncemade.com/renaming-and-extending-easy-clearing-aka-clearfix/

Comment: this technique uses CSS Hacks for IE this makes the the CSS unvalid :/

Comment: No, it doesn't. It takes advantage of IE's CSS bugs, but nothing of it is invalid CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Using empty DIVs to aid presentation is generally bad practice. You might consider changing the CSS of the elements you to clear. A lot of the time clearing can be replaced by the use off `inline-block`. See http://google.co.uk/notebook/public/06909424369135510368/BDROpQwoQ4-fhwfsj#SDRZLQgoQtfHkwfsj.

Rich

Comment: i know that it is a bad practice, i have not done the site, i just have to solve this problem.

Comment: Fair enough, I know that pain all too well.