# Setting all CSS heights to 0px leaves rendered height > 0

Tags: html, css

The following example defines two styles: `undisplayed` which simply sets `display:none`, and `noheight` which sets all height properties in the Box Model to 0px. It also sets `line-height` and `overflow` according to the advice in [Div height:0px does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950829/div-height0px-does-not-work).

There is a paragraph in each of these styles, with a horizontal line above and below it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
    <title>noheight &ne; undisplayed</title>
    <style>
      .undisplayed {
        display:none;
      }
      .noheight {
        max-height:0px;
        height:0px;
        border-width:0px;
        outline-width:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:0px;
        padding-top:0px;
        padding-bottom:0px;
        visibility:hidden;
        line-height:0px;
        overflow:hidden;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>undisplayed:</h3>
    <hr/>
    <p class="undisplayed">text</p>
    <hr/>
    <h3>noheight:</h3>
    <hr/>
    <p class=noheight>text</p>
    <hr/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tested this on Firefox 23.0.1 and Safari 6.0.5. In both cases, the gap between the two horizontal lines surrounding the `noheight` paragraph is bigger than that around the `undisplayed` paragraph. Why?

I'm interested in finding out why for two reasons:

1. I hate a mystery.
2. I've been playing with CSS animations to make some content contract in height to nothing. With an animation that changes the height properties mentioned in the `noheight` class, I'm always left with extra vertical space. I know I can do this with jQuery, and that my efforts to do so with CSS animation will probably not look as slick, but I am experimenting in order to improve my understanding.

I expect that my list of properties for the `noheight` style is an overkill, with some redundancy. If so, what is redundant (i.e. can be safely omitted on, say, recent(ish) versions of Chrome, IE, Firefox and Safari)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

As `.undisplayed` element has `display` set to `none` he is removed from the visual tree, therefore margins from the two surrounding `hr`s are **collapsed**.

For a `.noheight` element however, that is not the case, the element is still present and rendered (as 0px high) so margins **can't collapse**.

Comment: `display: none` does not mean an element is removed from the DOM. It is only removed from the visual tree.

Comment: Setting `margin: 0px` on the `hr` should overcome this right?

Comment: @Harry It depends on what you are trying to do. Setting `margin: 0` is different to removing extra space.

Comment: @Harry Having looked at the link provided by Jakub, if we want the `noheight` to display the same as the `undisplayed`, we need to set `margin-bottom` on the `hr` above the `noheight` and the `margin-top` on the `hr` below the `noheight` so that their sum is the same as the larger of the corresponding values for the `hr` elements around the `undisplayed` para. Hope that makes sense! This is because, on collapsing margins, the larger of these two values will be used. So, 0px may not be right. e.g. If `hr` margin was 8px, setting it 4px works.