# Will a div with height 0 and width 0 part of render tree?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `width: 0;` and `height: 0;`, I know it will be part of DOM tree but not sure if it will be part of CSSOM or Render tree.

```
<div style="height:0; width: 0;"><div>
```

Just to remove any complexity assume there is no child to this div, neither any other extra css style associated.

e.g. like `display: none` are part of DOM tree but not part of CSSOM or Render tree.

Comment: is this answer of your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803434/setting-all-css-heights-to-0px-leaves-rendered-height-0#answer-18803494

Comment: It does give a hint, but not clear. If I understand that correctly margin is working when its relative to `height: 0` element however it doesn't when applied relative to `dispaly: none` so if i try to infer answer from there it seems like `height:0` element will be part of CSSOM & Render tree.

Comment: I suppose it will be because such div can contain content and the content will be visible

Comment: if you applied some `border` or `padding`, this works. so `CSS` is working on `height: 0`/`width: 0` elements... also if you put a `<img>` inside that `<div>`, is displayed fine (but the `border` is displayed as a little dot).

Comment: Yes given that if we put some child It would overflow which again does give hint that It is part of CSSOM and Render tree

Comment: It must be rendered as it can easily be a flex or grid item, and as such, still affect the layout. Also any `:nth-child` etc pseudo selectors may affect it, or other elements due to its presence in the DOM. To decide this up-front when rendering would probably create a very sluggish rendering performance.