# CSS: Valid to set height to 0?

Tags: css

Is is valid/legal css to set a height of 0 to achieve the same effect as display: none?

```
.item {
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L0o1spko/

Comment: Valid, yes, working, not so much. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950829/div-height0px-does-not-work

Comment: why not ? does it work for you ?  but notice that there is a difference : https://jsfiddle.net/L0o1spko/2/

Comment: no not width still exist just to do     border: 1px solid black; and see then you have to set width 0 also see here https://jsfiddle.net/2gw56egw/2/

Answer (score 1):

It's valid, but not the same. If you have a fixed element (for example) inside that the it will still show unless you set its parent as `display:none`:

https://jsfiddle.net/L0o1spko/1/

```
.item1 {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fixed { position:fixed;}

.item2 {
  display: none;
}

<div class="item1">
    This content has a height of 0.
    <div class="fixed">
        sdfsdffsfsdf
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item2">
    This content has a display of none.
    <div class="fixed">
        sdfsdffsfsdf
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is totally valid to set height to 0 and can be used for many things such as animations where your content "slides in" from nothing.
There is nothing wrong with the notion and you may need it pretty often.

However, if I were you i would question why you would use it instead of display none ? If it is just to hide an item, then it is actually wrong in a semantic way, and you should avoid doing this if you can.
On the other hand, if you have a good reason similar to my explanation before, go for it, there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

It is legal, but you may also want to set `position: absolute` as well as `visibility: hidden` just so that it doesn't take up any space nor any of it's children or contents shows up on screen.